# how can i access file from aliasepath in context.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, server

```
  i add a aliases in my context.xml page
   <Context docBase="My_project" path="/My_project"aliases="/pathimg=E:\Images"/>
```

How can i access image from this aliase location??

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation

Comment: @ Stefan: how can i access this image to html img tag